# Is 'Google App Engine' far more expensive than 'Google Compute Engine'?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

I would like to setup server for 'image processing' activity on my website. What is the comparable power in GAE if I use 'n1-standard-1' instance in GCE? It is because I miscalculated it, or the price difference is substantial between the two for the same power?

Answer (score 6):

App Engine instances are more expensive than Compute Engine instances on a per hour basis. If you have a constant load, it's cheaper to keep a GCE instance running.

App Engine has an advantage that it can scale down to zero instances after 15 minutes of inactivity. If you have no load during long stretches of time (night, weekends) or few requests that come less frequently than ~ once per hour, App Engine instance maybe a more efficient solution.

Also, take a look at Google Cloud Functions. This is a Node.js runtime that is priced to 100 milliseconds. There are no instances to start or shutdown, no ongoing costs at all - you pay only when you process a request. And you get a free daily quota. The only limitation is that an individual request should be completed in 9 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the input Andrei. My first option is actually using 'Functions', however there are 2 major reasons why I'm not using it. My sever location is in Taiwan and 'Functions' is located only in USA. Another reason is 'Functions' is currently on 'beta' (might not be stable).